# Laravel | Query ordenada e apenas os últimos 3 resultados

Tags: laravel, query

Estou aqui com uma pequena dificuldade em colocar uma query a funcionar da seguinte forma:
Apenas os últimos 3 resultados mais recentes.

```
$noticias = noticia::limit(3)->get();
```

Mas agora quero seja ordenado pelo id do mais recente.
Normalmente uso :

```
orderby('id', 'desc')
```

Mas como consigo ter o limit e o orderby em simultâneo ?

Answer (score 0):

Neste caso seria:

```
$noticias = noticia::limit(3)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

tudo o que envolve a query deve ser antes do `->get()`, pois este executa de fato a query e retorna a collection.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez isso resolva. Já usei em um projeto e funcionou.

```
$noticias = noticia::orderBy('id', 'desc')->take(3)->get();
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).